# Responsive Images in a WordPress Blog Post

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, responsive

I published the first version of a WordPress site last week, and I am having a really difficult time figuring out the best way to have responsive images *inside* blog posts.

[Example of a blog post with wonky images in the body](https://genofevephotography.com/2017/12/21/merry-christmas-from-the-rameys-in-their-natural-habitat/).

I experimented with `max-width: 100%;` and `width: 100%;` for "img" tags, but they are still not displaying correctly, especially at smaller screen widths. I think what is throwing things off is that WordPress is adding "height" and "width" attributes to each img tag.

I'm getting pretty overwhelmed trying to find an answer to this dilemma, and I feel like other people would have had this same issue.

Comment: Hey, you are right, it is the properties in HTML that make your images stretch. 

<img class="aligncenter wp-image-167 size-large" src="https://genofevephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/DSC_3069-1024x683.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="427"> 

As you can see from the example, you have width and height.

You have to add height: auto to your image tags.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I had a feeling it was a really simple thing that I was missing :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Class "img-responsive". Please try this code

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-167 size-large img-responsive" src="https://genofevephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/DSC_3069-1024x683.jpg" alt="" width="640" height="427">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that you can do to ensure that your images always display well.

**Setting `max-width`**

It is a good practice not to exceed the original width of the image if it is not a scale-able image type.

**Setting `width` to `100%`**

When you are scaling an image down and the width is set to `100%`, you must free the height by setting the `height property value` to `auto`. That way, the image will scale-down without deteriorating

```
my-image-holder {
width: 500px; /* can be = or < the images original width */
height: 400px; /* Assuming you do not want the original height */
overflow: hidden; /* Hides vertical overlaps */
}

my-image {
width: 100%;
height: auto; /* Allows the image to scale accordingly */
}
```